# VBA slicing arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, slice

I am trying to slice several columns out of my original array "dataset" this does not work and I don't know why, could someone please provide some insight here?

```
Sub Pooling()

dim dataset()    
Dim rows As Long
Dim columns As Long
Dim varTemp()

rows = ShUnicorn.Cells(ShUnicorn.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
columns = ShUnicorn.Cells(1, ShUnicorn.columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
dataset = ShUnicorn.Range(ShUnicorn.Cells(1, 1), ShUnicorn.Cells(rows, columns))
varTemp = Application.Index(dataset, 0, Array(5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18))


For i = 1 To 5
    For j = 1 To 5
        shSmear.Cells(40 + j, i + 3).Value = varTemp(j, i)
    Next j
Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem. What does it do and what it should do, please give us an exemple

Comment: `Array(5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18)` are the columns that you want to retain?